# Spring JDBCTemplate on Seam-based app

Tags: spring, jdbc, seam, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

When manual SQL is required (JDBC API with pre-written queries), what is the best approach in a Seam-based application ?

In [Seam Documentation](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/HowDoIUseJDBCWithSeam), use of Spring bridge to inject a Spring JDBCTemplate is defined as the most complex to setup, but the easiest for development.

Do you agree with that ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use EntityManagers `createNativeQuery()` method. So you don't need spring perform native queries in a seam application.